# Attach events to child controls in JQueryUI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am relatively new to JQuery and my experience with JavaScript hasn't been much more than UI glue to HTML forms than in-depth programming (i.e. limited DOM-client-side events for client side validation and  making the UI more responsive and useful.)

I am tasked to extend an existing application to add a quality improvement module.  This application uses JQueryUI extensively.  I need to display a dialog box that contains a table with four controls, and I need to have JavaScript react to the events of the control in JavaScript.

For example, I need to have the contents of one SELECT box change depending upon the selected value of the value of another SELECT box.

I worked out the JQuery and JavaScript in an html document, and it worked fine, but when I put the controls in a JQueryUI dialog box (by passing the DIV containing the controls), the linkage between the events and controls are broken in a strange way.

The events fire properly, but when the function references the controls, the values returned are the values of the original HTML page, not the controls in the dialog box.

It seems that JQueryUI creates a new HTML page and hovers that over the original HTML page.

I have been searching for two days for a solution to this problem, but have not found an answer.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="editTest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="showQISection"  
       value="Enter Quality Improvement Data" 
       onclick="showQISection_click(this);" />
    <div id="QIDetail" style="display: none" title="Quality Improvement">
      <table id="atable" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;">
        <tr>
          <th style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">Topic</th>
          <th style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">Specfiction</th>
          <th style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">Notes</th>
          <th style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">Command</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
              <select id="QITopic" name="QITopic" onchange="QIoptionCheck(this)">
                <option value="none">Choose</option>
                <option value="one">Option One</option>
                <option value="two">Option Two</option>
                <option value="three">Option Three</option>
                <option value="four">Option Four</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top:1px solid black;"><select id="QIDetails"></select></td>
            <td style="border-top:1px solid black;"><textarea id="notes" rows="3" cols="25"></textarea>
            <td style="border-top:1px solid black;"><button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="button" onclick="Finish()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript and JQuery Code:

```
$( document ).ready(
    function() {
        $('#QIDetails').hide();

    }
);
var rows=[];
function aRow(id,topic,spec,notes)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.topic=topic;
    this.spec=spec;
    this.notes=notes;
}
function removeRow(d){
    $('#atable tr#'+ d).remove();
    for (var idx =0;idx < rows.length;idx++){
        if (rows[idx].id==d){
            rows.splice(idx,1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
function addRow(){
    var c= new Date();
    var d = c.getTime();
    var topic=$('#QITopic option:selected').text();
    var Spec=$('#QIDetails option:selected').text();
    var notes=$('#notes').val();
    rows.push(new aRow(d,topic,Spec,notes));
    $('#atable').append('<tr id ="' +  d + '"><td>'+ topic +
                            '</td><td>' + Spec + 
                            '</td><td>' + notes + 
                            '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="removeRow('+ d + ')">remove</button></td></tr>');
    $('#QITopic option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#QIDetails option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#notes').val('');
    $('#QIDetails option').remove();
    $('#QIDetails').hide();
}
function QIoptionCheck(){
    $('#QIDetails option').remove();
    alert('qitopic-'+ $('#QITopic').val());
    switch($('#QITopic').val()){
        case "one":
            $('#QIDetails').show();
            $('#QIDetails').append('<option value="oneone">Detail One-One</option>');
            $('#QIDetails').append('<option value="onetwo">Detail One-Two</option>');
            $('#QIDetails').append('<option value="onethree">Detail One-Three</option>');
            break;
        case "two":
            $('#QIDetails').show();
            $('#QIDetails').append('<option value="twoone">Detail Two-One</option>');
            $('#QIDetails').append('<option value="twotwo">Detail Two-Two</option>');
            $('#QIDetails').append('<option value="twothree">Detail Two-Three</option>');
            break;
        case "three":
            $('#QIDetails').hide();
            break;
        case "four":
            $('#QIDetails').hide();
            break;

    }
}
function Finish(){
    $('#results').empty();
    for (var idx =0;idx < rows.length;idx++){
        $('#results').append('Topic-' + rows[idx].topic + ' ' +
                             'Spec- ' + rows[idx].spec + ' ' +
                             'Notes- ' + rows[idx].notes + '<br/>');
    }

}
function showQISection_click(obj){
    var dlg = $('#QIDetail').clone();
    dlg.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            Close : function() {
                $(this).dialog('close').remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where in the code you shared are you getting the wrong value?

Comment: in the switch statement, regardless of what value I select, $('#QITopic').val() always returns 'none'.  Before using JQueryUI Dialog, this returned the right value.  My guess is that the JavaScript function is looking at the controls in the DIV on the page instead new HTML document JQueryUI created for the dialog box.

Comment: Why are you calling `$('#QIDetail').clone();`? That's going to cause a duplicate ID in your DOM. It will also strip events from contained elements.

Comment: I copied the code from another dialog box in this project.  Since it worked in the other instance, I just assumed it was the correct way of doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `$.clone()` on an ID. The way you call `.clone` also doesn't copy any attached events. You can remove the dialog by using the [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy) method.

```
var dlg = $('#QIDetail');
dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    buttons: {
      Close : function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
              }
    }
});
```

This will return the DOM to the "pre-init" state.